# MySQL: JOIN these two tables and fill missing values with the most recent ones

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following table `months`

```
date (date)
-----------
2016-11-01
2017-12-01
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
2017-04-01
2017-05-01
...
```

As well as the table `weeklyhours`

```
date (date) | hours (time)
--------------------------
2017-01-01  |   05:00:00
2017-01-03  |   12:00:00
```

I want a SELECT query to combine both tables and get the following output `result`

```
date (date) | hours (time)
--------------------------
2016-11-01  |     NULL
2016-12-01  |     NULL
2017-01-01  |   05:00:00
2017-02-01  |   05:00:00
2017-03-01  |   12:00:00
2017-04-01  |   12:00:00
2017-05-01  |   12:00:00
...
```

So I need to join the `weekylhours` table with the `months` table, but I fail with that. I've tried it the last two hours without success.

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: what is the condition you are trying out?

Comment: I've tried it with an additional JOIN where I get the most recent date, so that I can use the same value for the following dates. With a simple LEFT JOIN (see answer by Yousaf) I'll get '2017-02-01' with 'weeklyhours'=5, but '2017-02-02' will have NULL as weeklyhours. But I need it to be 5 as well until '2017-03-01'

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here is an answer in case someone else needs it.  Also as a note, there is an error in the initial post.  The second date should be 2017-03-01 instead of 2017-01-03 (otherwise no monthly difference).

Overall this relies on 'weekly hours' being a cumulative value.  A period value would just require summing hours in the initial join instead of having to find a max date and then create the second join.

```
DECLARE @temp_months TABLE(
    [mth] [date] NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @temp_weeklyhours TABLE(
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Hours] [time] not null
)

INSERT INTO @temp_months (mth)  
VALUES  ('2016-11-01'),
        ('2017-12-01'),
        ('2017-01-01'),
        ('2017-02-01'),
        ('2017-03-01'),
        ('2017-04-01'),
        ('2017-05-01')

INSERT INTO @temp_weeklyhours ([Date],[Hours])  
VALUES  ('2017-01-01','05:00:00'),
        ('2017-03-01','12:00:00')

SELECT t.mth as [Date], [Hours]
FROM
        (
            SELECT m.mth, max([Date]) UseDate
            FROM    
                    @temp_months as m
                LEFT JOIN 
                    @temp_weeklyhours as w
                ON m.mth >= w.[Date]
            GROUP BY m.mth
        ) as t
    LEFT JOIN
        @temp_weeklyhours as h
    ON t.UseDate = h.[Date]
ORDER BY t.mth
```